# Why do I get error "/var/lib/pgsql/.role.sh: not found" from postgres in docker?

Tags: linux, docker, postgresql, psql

I have PostgreSQL running in Docker. The host system is Ubuntu 18.04.3. Every time I execute some SQL in PostgreSQL I get

```
/var/lib/pgsql/.role.sh: not found
```

Does anyone know why this is or at least what the `.role.sh` script is? The SQL code seem to work anyway though.

The container is running under a non-root user that exists with the same `uid`, `gid` on both the container and host, as per security recommendation.

Output of `SELECT version();` in container:

```
PostgreSQL 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [...]
```

Image of PostgreSQL command and error:

[image: Image of PostgreSQL command and error.]

Comment: So, does that `/var/lib/pgsql/.role.sh` file exist? I found a reference to it [here on this other site](https://simply.name/yet-another-psql-color-prompt.html).

Comment: Thx for the answer. It doesn't seem like it. I tried running ls -la /var/lib/pgsql in the container and it says there's no such file or directory. I don't really get what the file does from the site you linked (I am new to this) or why its trying to find this .role.sh script...

Comment: Well, I didn’t post an answer. I posted a comment. Comments are typically conversations to clarify issues. And answers are solid answers. I have no such thing. Hope you can resolve this!

Comment: Oops, wrong word by mistake although I actually did know that, thx anyway. I tried having having the .role.sh and the .psqlrc in the site you linked copied to the directory when building the docker image; still it tells me "not found". Which I find super strange. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I think your prompt is referencing `/var/lib/pgsql/.role.sh`. Check your `~/.psqlrc` file, specifically line starting with `\set PROMPT1`. If applicable remove the part with the reference:

```
%`/var/lib/pgsql/.role.sh\`
```

Alternatively you could add the missing script following this guide. It will display your current role in the PSQL prompt: https://simply.name/yet-another-psql-color-prompt.html